# Can't post question on freelance. Says 'this looks like spam.'

Tags: support, spam, filtering

The title pretty much tells you my problem, there is no other error message.  It is a lengthy question, that's the only thing I can think of.

*I just posted the original since it doesn't seem to matter.  This is the title:

> How do freelance web developers approach web security and liability?

The question is:

> Sooo many questions, where to begin?  With governments and huge
>   corporations spending god knows what on cyber security just to get
>   hacked I think it's safe to say that there is no such thing as a 100%
>   secure system.  So that begs the question as to what level of
>   proficiency is adequate before you can release your product into the
>   wild?  A question that is made even more difficult to answer due to
>   the fact that there is no industry-wide standard.  You have PCI-DSS
>   when dealing with credit cards, regulations you have to follow when
>   building for the health sector, and OWASP would be great if they
>   weren't waiting to replace their developer guide from 2005.  As it
>   stands there just isn't anything that neatly covers the current scope
>   of web development.
>
> I'm sure you get actors across the spectrum who deal with this in
>   different ways.  I'm sure some throw caution to the wind and release
>   every bug-filled app the minute it's done while others, like me,
>   disect every potential liability before even attempting to step into
>   the industry.  Really someone even as neurotic as myself wouldn't have
>   given this a second thought had I not read that people would expect me
>   to be liable in the event of a breach.  I mean all I want to do is
>   make a website for my client's collection of cat memes (I said my
>   client's, not mine.... okay maybe mine) and now you're telling me I
>   have to buy something called cyber insurance because I might get sued?
>
> I read somewhere something like 70% of websites have serious
>   vulnerabilities, which to me makes sense.  Realistically how can you
>   expect every two-bit blogger to have the same level of security as a
>   multi-million dollar corporation?  That sort of thing has to come at a
>   premium.  The crazy thing is actually hearing people call for the
>   heads of small or even single-man developer teams.  Expecting perfect
>   security when even the big boys are getting whacked, I mean hacked. 
>   I'm assuming the road to becoming a security guru is a long one and it
>   seems unreasonable to expect web developers to be there before they're
>   allowed to provide services.
>
> The End
>
> ..........
>
> ......
>
> .
>
> Okay here's my question.  Like I said I'm sure people approach this in
>   many different ways and what I want to get is a sense of common
>   industry practices and hopefully some advice to go along with it.  I'm
>   sure a lot of this will come down to the wording in the contract so
>   here we go:  Will something like "We are not a security company and
>   cannot be held liable for any losses incurred in the event of a
>   breach.  We do our best to yada yada," have any impact?  What if this
>   isn't a one-man operation and you're outsourcing the front-end, or
>   vice-versa.  Does 'who's responsible' rely on the contract also or is
>   it more important where the breach occured (front or back)?  What if
>   you're outsourcing the actual security (not sure how you would do
>   that, maybe testing)?  Who's liable?  Is insurance a serious
>   consideration in the event of a lawsuit?
>
> I need to know what happens if you have an agreement to maintain the
>   site after it's launched - this is actually the topic that got me
>   interested in the first place.  When I first searched the issue of
>   liability on stack the consensus was if you were contracted to
>   maintain the site after the build then yes you would be held liable. 
>   Now at first glance that might seem logical but I think you have to
>   look at where breach occured.  It seems reasonable to expect software
>   updates and security patches to be included under maintenance and if
>   an attack was possible because you failed to do so in a timely matter
>   than yes you should be held liable.  A breach under any other
>   circumstance I would say no because again as a lone developer or small
>   team you can't be expected to code for every possible exploit, I mean
>   just think about all the Wordpress developers and the fact that they
>   might be subject to a lawsuit.  How can you expect developers to
>   contain, remove, and repair after an attack correctly when they're not
>   even equipped to do so?  These aren't web security experts and they're
>   going to be navigating uncharted waters.  Given the nature of the
>   situation they also won't have the time to learn on the go.
>
> What I'm looking for is ways to mitigate all of these potentials both
>   in the contract and outside (because apparently even legal wording may
>   fail to protect you).  How do some of you write security before and
>   after a breach into your agreement, including disclaimers and how to
>   handle the issue?  If using third-party security what's the legalese
>   in regards to responsibility for payment?  Do things like scope of
>   maintenance and complexities brought on by subcontracting the project
>   require consideration?  As you can see this is a wide-ranging topic
>   (probably beyond what I've included) and I'd like to get as complete
>   of opinions as possible.  These of course will not be taken as legal
>   advice so feel free to chip in and bring anyone who might have
>   valuable insight or authority.
>
> The End

Comment: Make sure it has no links, to begin with. If it goes through, try editing the links into it later.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Yeah it doesn't have any links, would the length of the post have anything to do with it?  We're talking 5-6 paragraphs here.

Comment: No, length shouldn't be any indication for spam. Another option is your IP address is being black listed due to massive spam coming from it, if you can try using different IP address it can prove/disprove this.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard By the way everytime I have to try to login a couple times because of 'suspicious request' warning.  Thought it might be an indicator because i heard that was an ip address issue as well

Comment: Why do you have two "The End"? Why all those dots? If it's part of your real question it's really poor writing, consider rewording and try again. Also, better get to the point sooner, without going around in circles.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard It was an attempt at humour to note the length of the post.  As I mentioned to ChrisF I tried reposting after removing that format and it didn't make a difference so I put the original here.  I may have been able to make the question more concise but it's a complex legal one and I presented it in a way I felt was inclusive of the whole situation.  I'll try ip switching since that's the onky lead Inhave at this point.

Comment: Well, as the answer by Robert says, the question is not good fit for Stack Exchange site, but can't see any reason why it's detected as spam. Hopefully a shorter, simpler, question, will pass through.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Unfortunately I'm still stuck on my phone so I guess it's a mystery for now.  I'm going to edit the question via Robert Longston's suggestion.  If you can I'd appreciate if you could review the edit for compliance.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard NM I just found out I'm supposed to be asking at meta.freelance

Comment: @Ian Not really, the spam filters might be buggy, and this is the proper place to report it.

Comment: Well, what. I just tried posting your question on there and [it got posted](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3344/how-do-freelance-web-developers-approach-web-security-and-liability) (self-deleted, 2k+ only). It seems your IP is somehow inside range of known spammer... and I see that you have successfully [posted your question](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-do-freelance-web-developers-approach-security-and-liability), albeit very different.

Comment: @Andrew T.  "IP in range of known spammer" is that something I should be concerned about?  Even if your IP constantly changes does the site keep the one you logged in as for the entire session?

Comment: This one, I can't say since I'm not the developer. It could be possible, since spammers are also trying to avoid block with changing IP, but that's only my theory. Looking forward for answer from official.

Comment: @Andrew T Got it, reason I ask is because I have to try multiple times when logging into any stack site and I read it has to do with IP switching (guessing it's my VPN).  Can't say for sure but I feel like I must have tried re-logging to post.  I definitely tried posting multiple times in same session and if IP switches so much that every log in is an issue and I couldn't post because of (maybe) IP then they must be keeping 1 address for the session (if that makes sense).  Interested in an official response too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a spam-detection system that blocks posts which have a very high similarity to posts previously detected as spam.

It's pretty conservative. But we made it a bit less so recently, due to a flood of spam from scammy tech-support companies. In spite of this, the false-positive rate on detection has been *extremely* low - but your post managed to use enough keywords to get bit.

I've tweaked the settings a bit - that said, I would join the others here in encouraging you to edit your post before submitting it. In addition to avoiding filters intended to catch verbose spammers, getting to the point in your question will also avoid the ire of those you may wish to see answering it.

Comment: I edited my post and that seemed to do the trick.  I'll make a note of keeping my questions to the point in the future.

Answer (score 17):

> Sooo many questions, where to begin?

Oh dear. You need to ask only one at a time.

> With governments and huge corporations spending god knows what on cyber security just to get hacked I think it's safe to say that there is no such thing as a 100% secure system. So that begs the question as to what level of proficiency is adequate before you can release your product into the wild? A question that is made even more difficult to answer due to the fact that there is no industry-wide standard. You have PCI-DSS when dealing with credit cards, regulations you have to follow when building for the health sector, and OWASP would be great if they weren't waiting to replace their developer guide from 2005. As it stands there just isn't anything that neatly covers the current scope of web development.

This is just stuff to read through that anyone likely to be able to answer the question already knows. Those folks are already starting to wonder where the question is and whether to bother reading on. I'm going to skip some of it now.

> ... now you're telling me I have to buy something called cyber insurance because I might get sued?

Thought that might be the question finally, but it seems rhetorical. Experienced answerers are close to giving up now. There are many shorter easier questions to answer.

Finally a few paragraphs on there's something about how to word a contract. That's a legal question that only  lawyer can answer. So you can't post that on freelance. You could try the [legal beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) but only if you massively edit the question into this single point and write out the exact phrases in the contract you intend to put in so they can comment on them. They won't work with

> yada yada

After that you seem to continue with additional stuff to wade through and then another question

> How can you expect developers to contain, remove, and repair after an attack correctly when they're not even equipped to do so?

That's not a legal question so it can't go on the aforementioned legal site. It is way too broad as a single question. What kind of attack? What was the effect? What infrastructure do you have? I.e. is it yours or hosted? etc, etc, etc. You need to provide exact details and ask a much more specific question.

And then we're back on the long long question road again.

> As you can see this is a wide-ranging topic (probably beyond what I've included) and I'd like to get as complete of opinions as possible.

Oh dear, now we're off topic as no Stack Exchange site allows questions about opinions. They all want something where an expert can supply an answer based on the facts presented in the question.

And you've cut it down already? From what? Your unpublished series of novels?

Oh and by the way the statement above seems to be missing a word or two, as written it doesn't actually make sense.

So if you've got this far, stop the stream of consiousness rambling and ask a simple direct question, otherwise even if you do get past the spam filters, you won't get an answer and you'll just waste everyone else's time reading as much of it as they can be bothered with before closing it.

Comment: Was the actual structure of my post what marked it as spam?  If both opinion and legal question are not allowed can I still ask for examples on how others form their contracts?  I'll try to edit the question with that in mind and omit the parts you suggested.  Can you review the edit once I do?  continued....

Comment: I gotta imagine a lrg portion of freelance.stack is about contracts (and ultimately legality, just with disclaimers).  The bit about the attacks wasn't a question per say, it was more a statement that expecting non-security experts to be equipped to handle a wide range of protocols is faulty.  I did note in my question nothing would be taken as legal advice, I'm just trying to adopt from common practices.

Comment: @IanLast We don't know exactly how the spam filters work. Presumably such information would be useful to spammers and so is not disclosed. On this site you'll just get general advice. The best places to ask about exactly how to write a suitable freelancing question are http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/ or http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing

Comment: I wasn't aware there were individual metas.  Thanks I'll look for advice over there.

Comment: Sorry Robert but this does not explain why it's blocked as **spam**. Low quality is a totally different issue than spam, and in the very least should give the user proper message.

Comment: It doesn't. Any more details in the error message could be useful to spammers so it's swings and roundabouts there. My answer does, however give the OP a better chance of getting somewhere if he does manage to get past the spam filter and it was way too long to post as a comment. Basically he's got two problems, one explicit and one implicit and I addressed the implicit one since only a developer could address the explicit one.

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happened to me today. There was nothing in my post that looked [to me] like spam and in the end it didn't appear that it was but I couldn't get past the red label telling me post couldn't be accepted.

I was also unable to find out any information about what spam looks like so I could adjust the post. Maybe I was looking in the wrong area - am new to this site so thats quite possible, but with pretty much everything else on this well organised site when there is a question or cause for finding out further information there is generally a well positioned link to adequate information allowing resolution of the problem.

*Would be helpful if there was an easily recognisable link to a page that helps resolve the problem in the red box that points to the post saying 'this looks like spam'.*

What I ended up doing was post in several increments, my logic was that I would then be able to identify the paragraph of the post that was causing problems for the system. None did, the post was eventually accepted without any adjustment in content.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, write most of the post elsewhere and paste it into the editor?

Comment: Not initially I didn't,  it was done in the box provided, wasn't done on freelance site, was on another stack exchange site. In the end I copied the post, pasted it into Mac Notes app, deleted all but the first paragraph online and posted and continued to do that till post was accepted as said above, without change. To clarify, this was the only site I was able to find information about this problem so if i have intruded i apologise.